# Superimpose a High Frequency AC Small Signal on a DC Power Signal

Tags: power-supply, coupling, modem, mixed-signal

I am facing a challenging problem with a circuit that I am currently working on, I would like others input and thoughts.

I have a DC power signal that I am injecting a AC small signal this mixed signal is transferred over two conductors to a receiver circuit which then uses the DC power signal to power a load and also extracts the AC small signal for use.

Description of signals:

DC Signal: 30V generated by a boost converter that has noticeable amounts of noise under the working load of 500mA to 1A

AC Signal: ~2vpp @ 1MHz to 30MHz

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMhq5D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is not an overly complex challenge given ideal components, however the real challenge I am seeing is the inductors sized to carry the currents required have a self resonant frequency typically <2MHz. From my understanding this means that they would not act as good filter component for the higher frequency AC small signal causing excess loading of the AC signal and a diminished signal at the receiver.

Very much looking forward to other's thoughts and opinions on the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you formulate that to a question? What inductors have you been looking at? COTS or wind yourself?

Comment: There are hundreds of inductors in 1uH-10uH range and >1 A current with self-resonance above 100 MHz.

Comment: What distance is this required to work over?

Comment: is that into 50  ohms? with 1A and how much attenuation of noise and what frequency is the noise.

Comment: @Ali Chen Based on the frequencies I'm looking to filter out I suspect that 10uH is on the low side (X (@1MHz) = 63ohm).

Comment: unless you define it you cannot design it

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I appreciate your input, I am mostly interested in the more "general answer" to this sort of problem.

Comment: There is no one filter fits all. You must define all source/load impedances , pass frequency and permitted attenuation and band stop and attenuation.  Otherwise it is pointless for an LC filter with DC and some noise and some signal. Then it becomes an XY problem with the properties of Inductors.

Comment: If your load switches 1 A and the inductor has 0.3Ohms, what is your load regulation tolerance? This inverse to source impedance. If you learn how to specify, you might just learn how to design.

Answer (score 1):

In the RF world, this circuit is called a *bias tee*.

You should realize that on the RF side, 1-30 MHz is a fairly wideband requirement, spanning nearly 5 octaves of frequency.

> the real challenge I am seeing is the inductors sized to carry the currents required have a self resonant frequency typically <2MHz

You may find that a series combination of inductors gives a better result than a single inductor. One with high value and low SRF, one with lower value and higher SRF.

Answer (score 0):

This is often done with coils or transformers to V+ with Common Emitter currents for AC to match load impedance and DC whatever coil and load requires.

Some CATV repeaters and many RF systems use AC or DC & RF on the same coax.

Start with specs for DC current, cable length and Signal impedance at source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ali Chen's comment I was able determine that there is a limit on inductance values available that have suitable SRF once you get into the higher frequency filtering applications.

I will be conducting some tests with lower inductance inductors around 10uH and check performance.

Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Please note that the answer feature is not supposed to be used for comments.